# How to access quicktext programatically within a LWC in utility bar?

Tags: lightning-web-components, quick-text

I have configured embedded chat in my website, and the agents are serving the customer chats via service console.

I have another browser extension which is used by customer support agents to load data about the customer. The communication between this extension and Service console is setup using a utility LWC component.

I have also enabled and configured quick text in Salesforce, and the agents can access them by clicking on the icon displayed in the service console UI.

The thing is, the browser extension also suggests what quick text template (using the ID of the quick text template) that can be used in a particular chat.

So, is there a way I can programatically select the quick text template using its ID from the utility component?

What I am currently doing is fetching the quicktext content via HTTP API, and sending the content alone to the LWC. Is there a better approach than this?